# How do I set a currency string value to a UITextField, preserving encoding?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I am developing an application in which I wish to handle different currency formats, depending on the current locale. Using a `NSNumberFormatter` I can correctly translate a number into string and back without problems.

But, if I put the string value into a `UITextField` and later get it back, I won't be able to convert the string back into a number and I will get a `nil` value instead.

Here is a sample code to explain the problem:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [Utils currencyFormatter];
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10000];
NSString *s = [nf stringFromNumber:n];
NSLog(@"String value = %@", s);
UITextField *t = [[UITextField alloc] init];
// I put the string into the text field ...
t.text = s;

// ... and later I get the value back
s = t.text;
NSLog(@"Text field text = %@", s);
n = [nf numberFromString:s];
NSLog(@"Number value = %d", [n intValue]);
```

where the `currencyFormatter` method is defined this way:

```
+ (NSNumberFormatter *)currencyFormatter
{
    static NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter;
    if (!currencyFormatter) {
        currencyFormatter  = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [currencyFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        if ([currencyFormatter generatesDecimalNumbers] || [[currencyFormatter roundingIncrement] floatValue] < 1) {
            [currencyFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
            [currencyFormatter setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.01]];   
        }
    }

    return currencyFormatter;
}
```

(The inner `if` is used to force the formatter to always round to the smallest decimal digit, eg. even for CHF values).

What I get in the Console is this:

```
2012-03-29 00:35:38.490 myMutuo2[45396:fb03] String value = € 10.000,00
2012-03-29 00:35:38.494 myMutuo2[45396:fb03] Text field text = € 10.000,00
2012-03-29 00:35:38.497 myMutuo2[45396:fb03] Number value = 0
```

The strange part is that the spacing character between `€` and `1` in the first line is represented in the console through a mid-air dot, while in the second line this dot disappears. I believe this is an encoding-related problem.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
Thank you!

**Edit**

I changed my test code to this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [Utils currencyFormatter];
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10000];
NSString *s = [nf stringFromNumber:n];
NSLog(@"String value = %@ (space code is %d)", s, [s characterAtIndex:1]);
UITextField *t = [[UITextField alloc] init];
t.text = s;
s = t.text;
NSLog(@"Text field text = %@ (space code is %d)", s, [s characterAtIndex:1]);
n = [nf numberFromString:s];
NSLog(@"Number value = %d", [n intValue]);
```

to discover this:

```
2012-03-29 02:29:43.402 myMutuo2[45993:fb03] String value = € 10.000,00 (space code is 160)
2012-03-29 02:29:43.405 myMutuo2[45993:fb03] Text field text = € 10.000,00 (space code is 32)
2012-03-29 02:29:43.409 myMutuo2[45993:fb03] Number value = 0
```

The `NSNumberFormatter` writes down the space as a non-breaking space (ASCII char 160), and then the `UITextField` re-encodes that space as a simple space (ASCII char 32). Any known workaround for this behaviour? Perhaps I could just make a replacement of the space with a non-breaking space but ... will it work for all the locales?

Comment: its not working for your currency locale only. i checked it and getting same null value as you said.

Comment: See my Edited answer second time. This may help you somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem only extending the `UITextField` through a custom class. In this new class I put a new `@property` of type `NSString` in which I store the "computed" string value for the text field. This string will never be modified and will preserve the original encoding of the content of the text field.

When you need to work again on the original untouched content of the text field you have to refer to this new property instead of referring to the `text` property.

Using a separate string container is the only way to avoid these strange encoding changes.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround: You could try to parse only the number values (and punctiation) via a regex pattern and create you currency value based on that number. If you do it in that way it is perhaps even more forgivable for the user, if he typed another currency symbol or other symbols that shouldnt be there...

Comment: I already do this in a previous version of the code. But I get strange errors, exceptions and crashes, probably with some strange locale. I really would like to use the magic of the `NSNumberFormatter` just to get rid of all that custom handling of the strings and to work in a "controlled" environment in which I encode and decode the strings/numbers using the same formatter object.

Comment: By the way ... what the user puts into the `UITextField` is actually generated through a call to the `stringFromNumber:` method of `NSNumberFormatter`, so I always know that what the text field contains has been correctly formatted. No need to add more logic to interpret that value.

Comment: Than you could just save the user-entered value for later usage? why do you need than to reconvert the textfield contents?

Comment: Because the "user-entered" value is written into the UITextField through the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method in the delegate class. This method will automatically convert user-inserted characters into currency formatted strings. The string is saved into the `text` property of the text field for displaying purposes and I get it back from here later ...